# Setting the IP address of a network interface which is not online (IPEnabled not true) / cable not connected?

Tags: c#, networking, wmi

Is it possible to set IP address (or anything else) for a network interface which is currently down?

I am using WMI, that means `ManagementObjectCollection` and `Invoke` methods. But it seems there is no way how to configure IP in c# on a network adapter which is currently down - cable not connected?

There is no error message.
For example, i set IP manualy for wifi interface, and by the WMI i want to set it to DHCP.

```
    ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where SettingID=\"" + selectedProfile.AdapterGUID + "\"");
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = query.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject newDHCPIP = mo.GetMethodParameters("EnableDHCP");
        mo.InvokeMethod("EnableDHCP", newDHCPIP, null);
        ManagementBaseObject newDHCPDNS = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
        newDHCPDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = null;
        mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDHCPDNS, null);
        ManagementBaseObject newDHCPRenew = mo.GetMethodParameters("RenewDHCPLease");
        mo.InvokeMethod("RenewDHCPLease", newDHCPRenew, null);
        mo.Dispose();
    }
```

I am 100% percent sure i am selecting right network adapter. But when i set it, and look at configuration (by windows network and sharing center, adapter properities) there is still static IP.

It is working only after i connect to the wifi network, then i look at configuration and there is DHCP

Comment: Too vague.  What's IPEnabled?

Comment: IPEnabled = true is set to the network interface when you ex. plug network cable to your network card, when is online... (on w7, on w2000 is allways true, but it is not important, important is how to set IP address to the network interface in c# when the interface is offline.

Comment: can you be more specific, in particular showing the code you're using for finding the interface and manipulating it that (presumably) works fine if the interface is up but fails to work if the interface is down, and specify how it fails (error thrown, object not found in WMI search query, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution will be to use `netsh`, because WMI is not working correctly.